# Как узнать какие элементы и сколько раз повторяются

Tags: массивы

Подскажите как правильно узнать какие элементы и сколько раз повторяются и если есть элементы которые не повторяются тоже бы узнать это, какой именно из элементов не повторяется... скажем если есть такой вот набор данных:

```
["vasa", "peta", "vasa", "serega", "vasa", "andrey", "dima", "dima", "sveta", "oleg", "oleg", "oleg", "oleg", "igor", "vasa", "stas", "stas", "oleg", "serega", "serega", "andrey", "mihail", "volandemort"]
```

Comment: На каком языке?

Comment: @post_zeew - на русском, это же русский StackOverflow.

Comment: @user3319778  Что означает "правильно узнать" по сравнению с "узнать" какие элементы и сколько раз повторяются?

Comment: @post_zeew Судя по профилю автора, либо на JS, либо га jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = ["vasa", "peta", "vasa", "serega", "vasa", "andrey", "dima",
            "dima", "sveta", "oleg", "oleg", "oleg", "oleg", "igor", 
            "vasa", "stas", "stas", "oleg", "serega", "serega", "andrey",
            "mihail", "volandemort"];

var result = {};
for(var iter = 0; iter < data.length; iter++) {
  var count = result[data[iter]];
  if (count) {
    result[data[iter]] = count + 1;
  } else {
    result[data[iter]] = 1;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Не повторяются элементы, у которых счетчик 1.